# Why this query is returning a error and no registers?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `entradas`
WHERE `categ` IN (7,2,1)
  AND `data-pagamento` >= '25-01-2020' AND `data-pagamento` <= '03-02-2020'
ORDER BY `categ` ASC
```

The query above is returning a error in the server and after error it is return no registers. I'm using a local server (XAMPP) and my phpMyAdmin version is 4.9.2, can someone help me?

Comment: Column data-pagamento data type?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `03-02-2020` is not formate for type date if your `data-pagamento` is date field

Comment: Its important to know what data column type `data-pagamento` is. Have you tried `DATE('25-01-2020')` for instance?

Comment: MySQL uses `YYYY-MM-DD` format for date literals. `'25-01-2020'` is NOT a date (in terms of MySQL), it is a string (which cannot be converted to a date). Use ``AND `data-pagamento` >= '2020-01-25' AND `data-pagamento` <= '2020-02-30'``.

Comment: This query returns no errors (it's just false because the dates are wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a proper  string conversion to date

```
SELECT *
FROM `entradas`
WHERE `categ` IN (7,2,1)
  AND `data-pagamento` >= str_to_date('25-01-2020', '%d-%m-%Y') 
    AND `data-pagamento` <= str_to_date( '03-02-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY `categ` ASC
```

and as a suggestion you could use also a between clause

```
SELECT *
FROM `entradas`
WHERE `categ` IN (7,2,1)
  AND `data-pagamento` between  str_to_date('25-01-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')      
    AND  str_to_date( '03-02-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY `categ` ASC
```

Comment: I disagree. Dates should be stored properly in the first place.